# How to convert RealmOptional to Int or Float in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I want to convert a type defined as `RealmOptional` to either `Int` or `Float`, depending on the type assigned to the generic. However, when I tried distributing them using `switch` statement, it turned out that not `RealmOptional<Int>()` but `RealmOptional<Float>()` were classified to `Int` cases. For example,

```
switch value { // value is of type AnyObject?
    case is String:
        cell.valueLabel.text = value as? String
    case is Int:
        // RealmOptional<Float> are executed here
        let v = value as! Int
        cell.valueLabel.text = String(v) // Float is now treated as Int
    case is Double:
        print("double") // not printed at all 
        cell.valueLabel.text = String(value!)
    default:
        break
}
```

Why does `RealmOptional<Float>()` behave as `Int` here? And how can I set the text to the `value` correctly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lets assume your `RealmOptional<Float>()` variable is named `myFloat`. Then, use the getter for the RealmOptional:s (see [this git entry for Realm](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/RealmSwift-swift2.0/Optional.swift)) *underlying value*, `.value`, rather then checking the RealmOptional itself:

```
var value = myFloat.value // value variable now of type Float
```

---

Below follows and explanation of why the `AnyObject?` switches doesn't behave as you expect:

From [Apples Language Guide - Type Casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html):

> Type Casting for Any and AnyObject
>
> Swift provides two special type aliases for working with non-specific
>   types:
>
> - AnyObject can represent an instance of **any class type**.
> - Any can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types.

Hence, the `AnyObject` type can can hold instances of any class type, but the fundamental numeric types (`Int`, `Double` etc) in Swift are not of class type, but of structure type.

In the `switch` in your example, the `AnyObject` instance is not inferred but *cast* to the first possible successful downcast, which will be whatever `case` you put top-most that is of a numeric type. Hence, if you change the ordering of your `case`:s in the switch, the casting will change.

```
let value: AnyObject? = 30.0
// try change the order
switch value {
case is String: print("string");
case is Float: print("float"); // hits `Float` downcast first -> prints float
case is Int: print("int");
default: print("other")
}
```

Now, you could, however, cast your `AnyObject` to an `NSNumber` (class instance), and continue from there. From [Working with Cocoa Data Types documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html):

> Instances of the Swift numeric structure types, such as Int, UInt,
>   Float, Double, and Bool, cannot be represented by the AnyObject type,
>   because AnyObject only represents instances of a class type. However,
>   when bridging to Foundation is enabled, Swift numeric values can be
>   assigned to constants and variables of AnyObject type as bridged
>   instances of the NSNumber class.

Note however that `NSNumber` is fundamentally different from the Swift numeric types (`Int`, `Double` etc) in that the former hold any kind of number, and allows us to cast this number to different type of numeric types. However, we cannot easily infer which type a specific `NSNumber` instance should be cast to, but we could implement our own (not so pretty) specification as how to infer different `NSNumber` to different swift fundamental numeric types.

**However, before proceeding with `NSNumber` hacking:**

From above, the core problem is that your `value` property is of type `AnyObject?`. Could you please post the code that lead to `value` being of type `AnyObject?`. Possibly the casting to `Int`, `Float` and so on if not necessary if using the getter of the RealmOptional (hence no need to casting `RealmOptional<T>()` to `AnyObject?`?).

Comment: Yeah, while you are correct that the first possible downcast is used in switch statement, I still want to convert a variable defined as `RealmOptional<Float>()` to `Float` (and not `Int`) and the same is true in the case `RealmOptional<Int>()`. Your second code is going to be executed in both `Int` and `Double`, which is not what I am going after...

Comment: Thanks. But the reason I have to switch it is because the type of the object cannot be judged at that time; in other words it might have been defined as `RealmOptional<Float>()`, `RealmOptional<Int>()`, or just a `String`. That's why it is first typed as `AnyObject?`, which I want to switch.

Comment: And the `value` variable in my original post is from my function, which returns `AnyObject?`.

Comment: @Blaszard When you say the `value` variable is from your function, do you mean that it's from a `RealmOptional<T>().value` getter, or something you've computed in a function of yourself? Cause even if you don't know what type your `RealmOptional` is of, you could still do a cast down switch (as? or is) on value even without knowing its type.

Comment: I return a property, such as `self.year`, where `year` is defined as `    dynamic var year = 0`, etc...

Comment: I found I should solve the issue by returning a struct that includes the value and a String or enum identifier to classify the types. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this is not related to Realm; it is related to Swift. In Swift when you pass a floating object in `switch`, it is not only caught up in `is Float` but also in `is Int`, because the floating number can be convertible to `Int` as well.

For example, the code below does not go through `is Float` condition, because it is caught up in `is Int`:

```
let value: AnyObject? = 30.0
switch value {
    case is String: print("string");
    case is Int: print("int");
    case is Float: print("float");
    default: print("other")
}
```

That is why `RealmOptional<Float>()` is caught up in `is Int`.

I still don't know how I can cope with the issue here, because an object of type `Int` is caught up in `is Float` and an object of type `Float` is caught up in `is Int`. Maybe someone can chime in...